# Custom Self Closing tags

Tags: pug, html-preprocessor

I'm trying to make a self-closing tag, like a

```
<customTag />
```

I tried using customTag /

how the documentation shows you how to do

https://pugjs.org/language/tags.html

but not when the code compiles it ignores my "/" and creates the tag

```
<customTag> </customTag>
```

Comment: have you read the answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely the self-closing tag  can't have the space between element and the `/`, so you need to remove the space, like this:

```
customTag/
```

Example:
[image: SS]